# redirect to 'market://details?id=my.package.name' fails in mvc controller

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect user to google play store app(NOT open play store in the browser). I tried this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult OpenApp()
{
    return Redirect("market://details?id=my.package.name");
}
```

It fails, and gives me this error: `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`.

This url works in javascript with `window.open(url,'');`, but I don't want to do it in js, I need to do this inside controller. I wonder what method should I use to redirect user to this url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect to *https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=...*
Android will automatically launch (or will suggest to launch) play store app unless user selected "Open this type of URL in browser" earlier.

Comment: the problem is we don't want to open the app in the browser. We want to open the play store app. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Try to open this link on your phone: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana It will lunch play store app.

Comment: I just tried the link with https, it opens in the browser without asking me to launch the app.

Comment: It opens PlayStore app on my Nexus 6. Let's see what other people suggest.

Comment: tried the second one without the https, opens in the browser too. I'm using a Nexus 5 emulator, if it matters.

Comment: I tried it on real device, turns out `https` works. Seems like it only doesn't work on emulator. So I'll just use `https`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although, the answer have been given. I'd like post another possible answer

```
"market://details?id="+ context.getPackageName().toString()
```